# How can I solve this recurrence relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Suppose $A_n = n + nA_{n-1}$,

How can I figure out an equation for $A_n$ in terms of $n$?

Let the base case $A_0 = 0$.

Comment: what is the base case i.e. what is $A_0?$

Comment: @happymath, A0 = 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this, I would substitute $A_n=nB_n$, which gives
$$
nB_n=n+n(n-1)B_{n-1}\implies B_n=1+(n-1)B_{n-1}\tag{1}
$$
Writing out a few terms, we can deduce the formula
$$
B_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k-1)!}+(n-1)!B_1\tag{2}
$$
This gives
$$
\begin{align}
A_n
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{n!}{(n-k-1)!}+n!A_1\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}+n!A_1\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}+n!A_0\\
\end{align}
$$
Note that for $n\gt0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n!}{k!}\\
&=n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{n!}-1\\[6pt]
&=\left\lfloor n!e\right\rfloor-1
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
A_n=\left\lfloor n!e\right\rfloor-1+n!A_0
$$

Answer (score 3):

I found $A_n = n! (\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k!} +A_0) $ for $n\geq1$

You can check $$A_{n+1}=(n+1)(A_n+1) = (n+1)\left(n! (\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k!}+A_0)+1\right) \\=(n+1)! (\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k!}+A_0) + \frac{(n+1)!}{n!} \\
= (n+1)!(\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}+A_0) $$